# help me to Evaluate the double integral

Tags: integration

Evaluate the double integral where I=∫∫xy dA where D is the triangular region with vertices  (0, 0), (5, 0), (0, 4).
I'm still having troubles to find the limits

my work so far , and I think that the limits are wrong

= integral(4 <= x <= 0, 0 <= y = 5 - x) xy dy dx 
integral(4 <= x <= 0) xy^2/2 (for 0<= y = 5 - x) dx

Comment: try to texify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. The line connecting $(0,4)$ and $(5,0)$ has equation

$$y = -\frac 4 5 x + 4$$

So the correct setup for the bounds is

$$\Large{\int_0^5 \int_0^{-\frac 4 5 x + 4} xy dy dx}$$

---

Note that the inequalities $4 \le x \le 0$ have no solution, so the given answer can't possibly be correct.

Comment: Thanks that really helped me!